# Multiple duplicated Views causes lag when added to layout

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, view

I am creating a space game where I am creating a random assortment of "stars" (small white circles) as part of the background. The shape is created in XML where the view is being created programmatically in Java. The stars are all essentially the same minus a random size and position. If I change the loop to only create 70 views or lower, the application as a whole runs fine with no slow downs on a Samsung Note 2. Ideally I would like to have a couple of hundred stars be created with no lag throughout the application.

stars.java

```
public void setup() {
    RelativeLayout fullLayout = (RelativeLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.fullLayout);

    //Creates a new "star" and adds it to my main layout as part of the background
    for(int i = 0; i < 750; i++){
        Random r = new Random();

        int width = r.nextInt(1000);//Using the dynamic screen size but for demonstration I changed the width & height to a hard coded integer.
        int height = r.nextInt(500);
        int starSize = r.nextInt(5) + 3;

        View star = new View(activity);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(starSize, starSize);
        star.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
        star.setLayoutParams(params);
        star.setX(width);
        star.setY(height);

        fullLayout.addView(star);
    }
}
```

star.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" >
    </solid>

    <!-- view border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#88FFFFFF" >
    </stroke>

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="90dp"   >
    </corners>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a ton of widgets/views, then Android gets really slow as it has to try and calculate where each one should be, and then it also has to draw each one individually.

For something like this you should create a single custom view which then draws all the stars in one go.

See here for more information on how to do that: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html